# Change in date format after exporting data.frame from R as .csv

Tags: r, excel, date, csv

It is a simple question but I couldn't find an answer.

I have this data.frame in R

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2001-01-05", "2000-05-13", "2000-07-22", "2000-07-22", "1990-11-03")))
```

I want to export it as .csv file where Month will be abbreviated (%b) and year will be year with century (%Y) as below

```
df1 <- df %>% mutate(date = format(as.Date(date, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%b-%Y"))
write.csv(df1, "df1.csv")
> df1
      date
1 Jan-2001
2 May-2000
3 Jul-2000
4 Jul-2000
5 Nov-1990
```

After I opened the df1.csv file, I found a different format for the date as below

[image]

I couldn't find the format month(abbreviated)-YEAR. Any suggestion how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the format in all the date cells in Excel.
Go to format cells and then change the format from

```
mmm-yy
```

to

```
mmm-yyyy
```

This format is not in the the list, change it in the box between "Type" and the format options list

Comment: Schilfini

Many thanks for your answer. It saved my time so I don't need to read data from .csv. I can't just open it then change the format.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an R issue. Excel has "helpfully" applied its own formatting to your data. To prevent this, you need to exert more control over the CSV import. [These instructions](https://www.hesa.ac.uk/support/user-guides/import-csv) may help you with that.

Comment: Many thanks. This fixed my problem. You are right it is not an R issue. I thought about asking it on superuser but I thought r users on SO might have experienced similar issue before.

Comment: Yes, you'll find that many R users have an opinion regarding Excel :)

Comment: You are right. I should not ask an excel question to R users :)